# Dialog text not showing in Angular 16 during an SSE stream

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, server-sent-events

In my Angular 16 application I am receiving streamed data from a medical device using Server Sent Events (SSE). I get the data, save it to an array, and display that array using an `*ngFor` loop in the usual manner. Of course I have to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after each event in order for the display to update in response to each SSE reception.

I display the results in an html table where each row has several `<td>` elements to display information about the measurement. In the first `<td>` element of the row I have an icon the user can click on to display the raw data received for this measurement in a dialog.

The problem is the **dialog pops up but is empty**. The data will continue to stream in (which the user can see but in the usual dialog fashion the user cannot interact with anything but the dialog).

Now if I unsubscribe from the SSE subscription (terminating the SSE), and then re-establish the SSE,  I can now see the raw data in the dialog for those previously received elements. But, for any new data that comes in, **the dialog is once again empty**. (I am populating the array with the most recent data being first `deviceObservation.observations.unshift(obs);` if that makes any difference.)

**What am I doing wrong?  Why is the dialog visible but empty ONLY for the currently streamed data?** Using console.log() I see that the data is retrieved from the array before being passed to the dialog. Would love to understand what is going on here!

Here is the `next` branch of my SSE subscription where `data` contains the raw measurement:

```
next: (data) =>
{
    // Makes a nice JSON FHIR Bundle object out of the raw data
    let deviceObservation: IDeviceObservation = this.fhir.getObservations(data);
    // Add it to the array of saved measurements
    this.fhir.msmtArray.unshift(deviceObservation);
    // Need this for the *ngFor loop to update the display in real time
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    console.log ("Msmt array length: " + this.fhir.msmtArray.length)
},
```

These are the methods called when clicking on the icon to display the raw data

```
  // 'index' is the element in the array to view
  viewBundle(index: number): void
  {
    this.jsonString = LZString.decompress(this.fhir.msmtArray[index].bundle); // Decompress
    this.jsonString = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.jsonString), null, 2);  // Turn to JSON object and then stringify 'pretty' with 2 space indentation
    this.openAddItemDialog({header: 'Received Bundle', title6: '', item6: this.jsonString, helperString1: 'Some_file.txt'});
  }

  openAddItemDialog(input: IDialogData): void
  {
    console.log("Dialog clicked to do: " + input.header);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open<IDialogData>(DialogComponent,
      {
        width: '96vw',
        data: input
      });
  }
```